# Automatic Slideshow Not Working JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I am currently trying to understand how to create a slideshow in JavaScript from W3Schools. The Manual slideshow worked perfectly but the automatic slideshow is not working in any way.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main_adverts">
        <img class="slide" src="images/imgslider1.jpg"/>
        <img class="slide" src="images/imgslider2.jpg"/>
        <img class="slide" src="images/imgslider3.jpg"/>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

CSS:

```
#main_adverts{
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 15%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#main_adverts img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? Are you getting any errors in the developer console?

Comment: No errors. The first image is displayed but nothing transitions.

Comment: Try moving your JavaScript to the end of the page before the closing body tag

Comment: That works! Thanks so much, sorry if it was a stupid question!

Comment: You were trying to execute code against elements that hadn't been rendered to the page yet

Comment: I understand, I'm still new to HTML, CSS and JS

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may come across this in the future. The safest way to solve this issue is to wrap your code like the following:

```
window.onload = function(){
    //Your code here
}
```

By doing so, regardless of where you place your JavaScript in the HTML file, it will wait to execute until the page has fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Put the js link in last line inside the body tag:

```
<body>
    <!- rest of your html -->
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```